# Can not access the static resource

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-cache, django-compressor, mezzanine

I'm using Mezzanine, django-compressor and amazon-s3. I use django-compressor to compress css file. I have deployed the website to Heroku and stored the static resource successfully. However, after a period, all the css are lost. And below is the notification from amazon-s3:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Request has expired</Message>
<RequestId>FCE5D863FC2EBB9D</RequestId>
<Expires>2012-11-16T17:30:01Z</Expires>
<HostId>
aXa9JBZWx5UiwJmIfpTXsUZgeNGQDONx0G/IezufvWv1FwAUlnK8bzo2u+Qdsenj
</HostId>
<ServerTime>2012-11-16T18:10:17Z</ServerTime>
</Error>
```

And this is the config in setting:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
ten_years = date.today() + timedelta(days=365*10)
# Expires 10 years in the future at 23h GMT
AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Expires': ten_years.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y 23:00:00 GMT'),
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=386900',
}
```

Please help me to resolve this problem. I can not find out the root cause.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of accessing signed url.You can do below setting in settings.py to avoid this

```
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```